# Is it possible to get all the test categories from mstest solution dll using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, mstest

Is it possible to get all the test categories from mstest solution dll using reflection?
I have tried the following:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
```

but when i attempt to get types from this assembly using,

```
var types = testAssembly.GetTypes();
```

it throws `ReflectionTypeLoadException`.

I believe once i get the types i can look for CutomAttribute 'TestCategoryAttribute'.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netcore-3.1), you should get a list of types which could be loaded with the exception. From that you can conclude which type couldn't get loaded. Is there something special with that type which could not be loaded?

Comment: See if your dll has dependencies, maybe other dll libraries, and make sure your program can load all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks armagedescu. I copied the other DLLs as well and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder from which I was picking the solution dll for fetching the types had only that dll. But it was dependant on some other DLLs as well. So when I copied all the other DLLs along with the main solution dll, I was able to get the types. And from those types I got the test categories.
Thank you.